# GitHub Actions: Setting Working Directory with Context Fails to Find File

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to set my working directory with an environment variable so that I can handle 2 different situations, however, if I use context with the working-directory it does not find files in the directory, but if I hardcode the path, it does. I have tried many different syntax iterations but will paste one iteration below so it is easier to see what I am trying to accomplish.

```
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      . . .
      - name: Monorepo - Set working Directory
        if: env.WASMCLOUD_REPO_STYLE == 'MONO' # Run if monorepo
        run: |
          echo "WORKING_DIR = ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/actors/${{ env.ACTOR_NAME }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Multirepo - Set working Directory
        if: env.WASMCLOUD_REPO_STYLE == 'MULTI' # Run if multirepo
        run: |
          echo "WORKING_DIR = ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Build wasmcloud actor
        run: make
        working-directory: ${{ env.WORKING_DIR }} # If I Hardcode path here it works
```

The environment variable is showing the correct path during debugging which is formatted as: `/home/runner/work/REPO_NAME/REPO_NAME/actors/ACTOR_NAME`

For step 3 if I type `working-directory: actors/ACTOR_NAME` it works (until a later issue :P where it again does not find a directory)

This is my first few days with GitHub Actions so help would be really appreciated. I am not sure why context is not being accepted but a static path is. Examples often show working-directory using context.

Comment: You shouldn't have blanks around `=` when assigning environment variables.

Comment: Also, it's not necessary to refer to `ACTOR_NAME` as `${{ env.ACTOR_NAME }}` within a `run` step; you can access directly as `$ACTOR_NAME`

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminW. That seemed to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See @Benjamin W.'s comments above for the answer.